# Any vulnerabilities found in the EVM or Ethereum Protocol?

Tags: blockchain, evm

I've read of several vulnerabilties w.r.t. blockchain technology, e.g., Bitcoin, that allowed hackers to steal currency tokens.

From my understanding all these "hacks" have resulted from either spoofing or websites being compromised.

Have there been found any vulnerabilities deep within the EVM or the Ethereum Protocol that allowed hackers to take over accounts and resulted in hotfixes?

Answer (score 1):

There were many yelling articles about Ethereum hacks. But so far they were all because of the vulnerabilities in 3-d party created contracts or unsecure currency exchanger websites. 
 So, I can assume the answer is no. Or not yet.

### List of "Ethereum" hacks

- [DAO hack explained (video)](https://youtu.be/5JrdR6SRlWE) *June 2016*
- [Parity hack explained (video)](https://youtu.be/1SIKEzNQcD0) *July 2017*
- [Second Parity hack explained (video)](https://youtu.be/1kMHwxJs2gI) *November 2017*
- [Bithumb hack (article)](http://fortune.com/2017/07/05/bitcoin-ethereum-bithumb-hack/) *July 2017*
- [CoinDash ICO Hack (article)](https://www.coindesk.com/7-million-ico-hack-results-coindash-refund-offer/) *July 2017*
- [Enigma ICO hack (article)](https://thehackernews.com/2017/08/enigma-cryptocurrency-hack.html) *August 2017*

---

*last update: 21.12.2017*

Comment: So, there haven't been any "hotfixes" to the EVM or Ethereum Protocol that addressed security issues?

Comment: I think to complete the answer you should reference which 3rd party contracts you're referring to and how it was at the contract level and not EVM level.

Comment: @Shuzheng last few hotfixes I've found were made in the fall 2016, `"hotfix release to mitigate last weeks DoS attacks"` [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases?after=v1.5.2)

Comment: But these are fixes to the client implementation itself. Has it been necessary to change the specification of the EVM or the Ethereum Protocol due to “bugs” (mistakes)?

Comment: @Shuzheng haven't seen any so far. But I will make a research.

Comment: EIP150 was a change of protocol to fix the gas price of some opcodes. There were DoS attacks that used cheap opcodes that caused lot of IO access, slowing down generation of new blocks and verification of transactions.